# Resetting color after a command

Tags: color

`\color` is turning the whole text into blue.  How can I modify the command such
that only `Info:` is shown in blue ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \this {}
  {
    \color{blue}
    Info: \hspace{5mm}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

 \this something something

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try localizing it by an extra pair of { } inside \this, wrapping all lines there.

Comment: another account? Use \textcolor{blue}{Info}.

Comment: Or you could try reading any basic tex documentation which would tell you about tex groups